# Data-Retrieval from Game Center and Google Play Games Services

Tags: android, ios, game-center, google-play-games

I intend to develop a multiplayer word game on iOS and Android (multiplayer for the first time). Does Game Center or Google Play Game Services allow me to retrieve history data from games played in the past?

I would like to use this data for analytics in the future.